# changed branch and local uncommitted changes

Tags: git, git-branch, git-stash

I have been working on a branch (BR1) and have made a few changes that I don't want to commit. For example, some local configuration. I have been told that branch BR1 has been renamed to BR2.

Now, this is what I did:
Save the local changes

```
$ git stash
```

Update branch information in my local

```
$ git fetch
```

point to BR2

```
$ git checkout BR2
```

(at this point, I have a detached head)

apply back my stash

```
$ git stash apply
```

What did I do wrong? or What do I need to do so that my working branch gets changed from BR1 to BR2 and still retain my local uncommitted changes?

```
$ git branch -a
*(detached from BR2)
master
BR1
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/BR2
remotes/origin/BR1
```

Comment: You say "re-base to BR2" but the command you list is git checkout BR2. Which was it?

Comment: updated my wordings, I was trying to point to BR2

Comment: So BR1 was a remote branch that was renamed to BR2?

Comment: yes, BR1 was renamed to BR2 which are remote branches that was updated on git by another person.

Comment: Are you on a detached branch directly after the checkout command? Git usually warns you about such situations.

Comment: What was the output from git checkout BR2? Also, are you in the middle of a rebase? You can check by seeing if there is a .git/rebase-merge or .git/rebase-apply directory present

Comment: git checkout BR2 output - Note: checking out 'BR2'. You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout. HEAD is now at 181894b... BR1 update to version 1.1.1

Comment: So the stash apply has nothing to do with the detached HEAD because you were already at that point. Is BR2 actually a tag and not a branch? Does BR2 show up when running git tag or when running git branch -a?

Comment: My [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19131468/6309) stands: create a local branch `BR2` with a starting point "`origin/BR2`".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `BR1` was renamed as `BR2`, that means the git fetch have brought "`origin/BR2`".

To be sure, I would:

- create a new local branch referring that new name:

  ```
  git checkout --track -b BR2 origin/BR2
  ```
- keep BR1 around (and then delete it if `BR2` looks good)
- apply the stash on `BR2`.